# Draw2D: How to use a port as source/target for more than one connection?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, draw2d-js

So, I'm trying to build as a personal project my course curriculum and I decided to use Draw2D because I think it's pretty complete. I'm representing the courses as rectangles and setting connections between them to show which ones are pre-requisites for other courses, something like this:

[image: Course list with dependencies]
The problem I'm having is  that when trying to make the same port the source for two connections it just takes one and ignores the other. Any ideas? Below is a quick sample:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // Create the paint area. The id in the constructor must be
    // an existing DIV 
    var canvas = new draw2d.Canvas("gfx_holder");

    // create and add two nodes which contains Ports (In and OUT)
    var start = new draw2d.shape.node.Hub();
    var startLocator = new draw2d.layout.locator.BottomLocator(start);
    var startLocator2 = new draw2d.layout.locator.BottomLocator(start);

    var startPort = start.createPort("output", startLocator);
    var end   = new draw2d.shape.node.End();
    var end2   = new draw2d.shape.node.End();

    canvas.addFigure( start, 400,100);
    canvas.addFigure( end, 200,150);
    canvas.addFigure( end2, 600,150);

    var c = new draw2d.Connection();
    c.setTargetDecorator(new draw2d.decoration.connection.ArrowDecorator());
    c.setSource(startPort);
    c.setTarget(end.getInputPort(0));
    canvas.addFigure(c);


    var c2 = new draw2d.Connection();
    c2.setTargetDecorator(new draw2d.decoration.connection.ArrowDecorator());
    c2.setSource(startLocator2);
    c2.setTarget(end2.getInputPort(0));
    canvas.addFigure(c2);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect your problem lies in the setSource function call.

```
c.setSource(startPort);
c2.setSource(startLocator2);
```

One seems to specify a port, and the other a Locator.

Comment: I really dropped the ball there :P